# Timezone change and Timestamp (Issue with Sync Framework)

Tags: sql-server, timezone, timestamp, microsoft-sync-framework

We have a primary database and a few clients that work offline and then sync data using Sync Framework. All data is updated within one scope, but each client works on a unique set of records.

Recently we had a mysterious error. One client updated all records in the primary database.

The client did not change all the data intentionally, but:

1. Changed timezone on the PC between syncs
2. Made a backup and then restored it on a different computer with a different timezone, then synced up to the primary database from that computer.

Sync Framework uses timestamps to know what data changed. Therefore, changing the timezone should not be an issue.

Can you think about any scenario when timestamp column can be modified during changing timezone or backup and restore procedure?

Answer (score 1):

what's the mysterious error you got?

when you do a backup and restore, make sure you run PerformPostRestoreFixup after you restore and before you sync the restored database.

likewise, in your scenario, even if you didnt run PerformPostRestoreFixup, if you say there was no record changed, it shouldn't have detected changes to sync.

Comment: I really forgot about PerformPostRestoreFixup. Thank you! But I agree that this shouldn't be the cause. Now I added audit tables to see if that will happen again.